# Winform width and height improper values

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting improper behavior in the size of the form,I set the values of the width and the height manually but the produced form is smaller than expected.

I made a simple form to illustrate my problem,The form is set to 400x400 in the IDE.

On the form there is three labels with text changing by the mouse move their code as follows:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "this.Width = " + this.Width.ToString();
        label2.Text = "this.Height = " + this.Height.ToString();
        label3.Text = "Mouse X coordinate = " + e.X.ToString() + "\nMouse Y coordinate = " + e.Y.ToString();
    }
```

And here is what i get:

**The width**

[image: The width]

**The height**

[image: The height]

Any ideas?

Comment: `this.ClientSize.Width` is different from `this.Size.Width`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: My guess that you set the whole form width/height (this includes titlebar and borders), you need to set the client area width/height.

Comment: Do you mean that this.width is the value of the form width including the borders?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows form size is 400x400 but active area excluding Titlebar and borders is different, Mouse Pointer gets coordinates as per active area. You can get active area size by `this.ClientSize.Width` and `this.ClientSize.Height`.

Set Client area to 400x400 (Change form size according to it) and it will show you correct result.